# Lost pictures in iPhoto

Tags: photos.app

I lost all of my pictures from my iPhoto after updating it to the newest version. How do I find them?

Comment: Did you already look (in Finder) into your Pictures folder? They should at least be still there.

Comment: After you find your images in the finder, run iPhoto, go to the File menu and choose "Import to library"

Answer (score 1):

Have you pointed iPhoto to your old library (In iPhoto: File>Switch to Library)?

I also recall that it said: "The photo library needs to be upgraded to work with this version of iPhoto." when I updated. Did yours do this? I notice also that there is a quit option, did you just click through thinking it was junk?

[image: Library Upgrade]

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do to get the photos back is hold down option and command keys while opening iPhoto and then click on rebuild database. They are all there... YAY